# Eclipse Jetty keeps asking for webdefault.xml

Tags: eclipse, jetty, osgi, embedded-jetty

I'm deploying all necessary Jetty bundles to an OSGi-container and launch a server instance. Yet although I'm deploying jetty-webapp and the corresponding jar contains the file `org\eclipse\jetty\webapp\webdefault.xml`, at startup I'm presented the error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\eclipse\org\eclipse\jetty\webapp\webdefault.xml
```

(`D:\eclipse` is the eclipse installation I'm launching from)

Why isn't Jetty using the file it comes with? When I copy the file from the jar to the requested location, Jetty runs fine - but that can't be a feasible solution.

I wouldn't mind having to provide the file, but then again I don't know how to pass the path to Jetty. The launch happens directly from within an eclipse launch configuration, no maven involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jetty-osgi-boot.jar, than you have to set the following system properties:

```
-Djetty.home.bundle=org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot
-Djetty.port=8080
```

The value is the symbolic name of the osgi-boot bundle that contains a default configuration.

More info in the documentation of jetty: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/framework-jetty-osgi.html

Alternatively you can use the org.apache.felix.http.jetty bundle. You can find information about it here: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html

Or you can use Pax Web: https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/Advanced+Jetty+Configuration

I used the jetty-osgi before. Nowadays I use the felix stuff as it can be configured via configadmin. Pax-web can also be used via configAdmin. I have not tried it yet but as much as I heard it has its benefits (e.g. better servlet context handling with HTTPService)

Comment: I did tests with the felix jetty bundle, but as it comes with Jetty 8 instead of 9 it's not an option. I tried adding the bundle you suggested and it shows as active, but putting the parameter into "VM arguments" at the eclipse launch configuration doesn't help. Is that the wrong place? So far I'm configuring Jetty from code, so theres no config file etc. I could use.

Comment: If you have not had the jetty-osgi-boot.jar before and you got the message, something else tried to start the jetty instance. When the jetty-osgi-boot tries to start it, the system property should work.

Comment: Forgot the jetty.port system property. Edited the answer with that. Jetty-osgi-boot needs that as well to start the jetty instance. The VM Arguments can be a good place. As your IDE is not in front of me, I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: Just as a quick side node regarding Pax Web, it can be used with ConfigAdmin as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the whole Pax stuff is not an option for my project at the moment, so I'll try going with jetty-osgi. I always thought that bundle would be more of an "addition" - don't know why I never figured that it already starts a server!